# Where are the modes for IO::File documented?

Tags: perl

Perl has modes for `IO::File` like `r` and `w`. **Where are these documented?** From `perldoc IO::File`

```
$fh = IO::File->new("file", "r");
```

I'm looking to find the character that corresponds to the mode to open the file for appending, and create it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Why not to look in **CPAN** documentation for the module? https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::File

Comment: @Robert see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Comment: @PolarBear it does not list all the acceptable open modes. Coincidentally, [File::Open](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Open#fopen-FILE) does.

Comment: @Grinnz -- at least it gives new pointers to continue search for the answer and eventually OP will hit **File::Open** for perl or direct pointer to **ANSI C fopen()** which OP should understand as `man 3 fopen`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> an ANSI C fopen() mode string ("w", "r+", etc.), it uses the basic Perl "open" operator (but protects any special characters).

So in [`man 3 fopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)

> The  argument  mode  points  to a string beginning with one of the
>          following sequences (possibly followed by  additional  characters,
>          as described below):
>
> - `r`      Open  text  file  for reading.  The stream is positioned at
>               the beginning of the file.
> - `r+`     Open for reading and writing.  The stream is positioned  at
>               the beginning of the file.
> - `w`      Truncate  file to zero length or create text file for writ‐
>               ing.  The stream is positioned  at  the  beginning  of  the
>               file.
> - `w+`     Open  for  reading  and writing.  The file is created if it
>               does not exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The  stream  is
>               positioned at the beginning of the file.
> - `a`      Open  for  appending (writing at end of file).  The file is
>               created if it does not exist.  The stream is positioned  at
>               the end of the file.
> - `a+`     Open  for  reading  and appending (writing at end of file).
>               The file is created if it does not exist.  The initial file
>               position  for  reading is at the beginning of the file, but
>               output is always appended to the end of the file.

Comment: Just wanted to add a link to the [perldoc open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) function.

Comment: Notably, the `b` accepted by `fopen` is not accepted by `IO::Handle->new` and `IO::File->new`.

Comment: Feel free to submit a documentation patch :) One shouldn't have to lookup the documentation for C's `fopen`, especially on a non-unix system.